# Flash file is not working in an html page

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, slideshow

I have a page that contains a Flash slideshow. Recently, it stopped working.  If I access the file directly, then everything is fine, but when I want to load the slideshow in my HTML page doesn't work. Can anybody see and help me why it stopped working?

This is the location of the page: https://www.sanmar.com/help/flash/order_data_export_slideshow.jsp

The direct path still works: http://www.sanmar.com/help/flash/quickbooks.swf

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem running it through SSL because some of the content isn't being returned as secure. It probably has to do with the headers not being sent back in a secure mode.  If you run it in Chrome you will get a warning that not everything is secure.

Some info from Adobe: [Flash Player Issues -  Secure Sockets](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-issues-secure-sockets.html)

[EDIT] One other thing I noticed are some references to Adobe's download areas in the code with http, e.g.

```
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','600','height','487','src','quickbooks','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','quickbooks' ); //end AC code
</script><noscript><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="600" height="487">
      <param name="movie" value="quickbooks.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <embed src="quickbooks.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="487"></embed>
    </object></noscript>
  </p>
```

And an image link near the bottom:

```
<div><img alt="DCSIMG" id="DCSIMG" width="1" height="1" src="http://wt.sanmar.com/dcsairxqntlbtj3wwflz3plo1_4d5g/njs.gif?dcsuri=/nojavascript&amp;WT.js=No&amp;WT.tv=8.6.0"/></div>
```

Be sure and change all of those references to **https**.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. but its my requirement to run through SSL .is there any other solutions so i can try

Comment: Check the Adobe link as it offers a suggestion like making sure the header cache is cleared.

Comment: To build upon this, you can solve it through changes in crossdomain-policy file. 

the "allow-access-from"-tag, has an optional secure attribute which defaults to true, If your policy file is on an HTTPS server and you want to allow SWF files on a non-HTTPS server to load data from the HTTPS server, you can set the attribute to false.
Here's a link to the adobe tech document describing the issue:
[Adobe-tech-document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reach https server but flash request content from http. Below link works fine

http://www.sanmar.com/help/flash/order_data_export_slideshow.jsp

You can change swf resources path as http if domain is http or https if you are using https request. Relative paths to resources would sort it out.